# consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://awaazde:**@rbmq.local:5671/awaazde: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amazon-ecs

I am using ECS with EC2 launch type, where my four services are running like Frontend in angular, backend in python django, redis and rabbitmq, Now my my backend is must connect with rabbitmq where  rabbitmq make connections with backend service and in backend service celery is there which is give workers to rabbitmq via ampq protocol now for i need to make connection with between two, and i have make connection via .env file.

I have enable Service discovery where i have made namespace named "local" , its automatically create privaate hostedzone named "local" into route 53 , now i have create service with service discovery.

In Local machine its working with mention envrionment "amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5671//" but in ecs  in task defination i have decair this environment varibale with service discovery namespace its give me an error like this " consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@rbmq.local:5671//: [Errno 111] Connection refused." - connot resove the DNS name

> Note: -  with out .env file not able to connect any service via mentions credentials,

Please help me with this.

I want to make it work by only task defination environment variable not by .env file and also its also able to resolve service discovery by create private DNS zone.